# Testing script is fine but running live is not

Tags: javascript, zapier

I'm using javascript to omit text after a trigger (---).  It works when I test it but it doesn't when I run it live. What I want to do is omit text after the 3 dashes when sending an instagram post to twitter.

```js
// input data:
"Testing #MaxxJams --- #MaxxMusic"

// desired output:
"Testing #MaxxJams"
```

Which is omitting everything after the 3 dashes. It works when I test, but when I run it live it shows the entire caption including the 3 dashes and everything after it.

Here is my code:

```js
var caption = inputData.caption.split("---");
caption = caption[0].trim();

output = [{caption: caption}];
```

In the editor: [image]

The test result: [image]

Notice caption doesn't show anything after the dashes. But when ran live it shows the dashes and everything after.

Comment: This is in Zapier

Comment: We will need more information. Are any errors thrown?

Comment: instead of setting `output` return data: `return [{caption: caption}]`

Comment: pmkro - no errors thrown

Comment: I will try your suggestion @ Remisa

Comment: @ Remisa   Tried it - Same result. Ran successfully.  No error but it still shows the tag after the dashes in the tweet.

Comment: where are the input strings coming from ? maybe they are a different character oO or have some invisible chars between them

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I took a look at your zap (the one that is currently on, id `55572226`) and the issue is twofold:

1. The input to the code step is literally `"Testing #MaxxJams --- #MaxxMusic"`, you'll want to change that to be the caption from step 1 (instagram)
2. The input for twitter is mapping the caption from step 1 instead of the result of your code from step 2. Once you map to that caption instead, it should work as expected.